# OSX Mavericks - disable network request after application build

Tags: macos, networking, mac, permissions, firewall

When I compile my application on OS X and then run it via openmp on 4 cores the OS X firewall constantly asks me regarding network permissions. (It doesn't need network permissions, so this is even more annoying.) Since the app runs on four cores I get the same message four times. And because I need to edit and recompile the app very often it is very distracting. Is there a way (without disabling the firewall) to prevent the firewall from asking all the time?
I need a solution from OS side, since my possibilities in editing the program are limited, it is part of a huge build and my changes are only in a minor part of it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be codesigned with your "Developer ID" for the Mac to trust it.

You can get a **Developer ID** from the Apple Mac developer program.

You can learn more about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

The Code Signing guide here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but what the heck, no?; I've seen some applications still ask, but maybe give it a try, and do let us know:

Go into `System Preferences`, Select `Security & Privacy`, authenticate by clicking on the lock if necessary and entering your administrator password, Select `Firewall Options...`, and add your application to the list, and set the selections to "Allow incoming connections".

Comment: Ty, but this is already the case. The application is in this list and still there is the request after each compilation.

Comment: Yeah, I have some app's that behave, similarly, and my solution may be yours, once I find it, of course.

Comment: Yes, please tell me if you find a solution. :)